# Least Median of Squares robust regression C++

Tags: c++, statistics, regression, eigen

I have a set of data `z(0), z(1), z(2)...,z(n)` that I am currently fitting with a 2 variables polynomial of the kind `p(x,y) = a(1)*x^2+a(2)*y^2+a(3)*x*y+a(4)`. I have `i=1,...,n` `(x(i),y(i))` coordinates that I impose to be `p(x(i),y(i))=z(i)`. In this way I have a Overdetermined System that I can solve  using [Eigen SVD](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__LeastSquares.html) . I am looking for a more sophisticated method that can take care of outliers, like a Least Median of Squares robust regression (as described [here](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/LeastMedianOfSquares.pdf)) but I haven't found a C++ implementation for 2 variables. I looked in GSL but it seems there is nothing for 2 variable functions. The only other solution I can think of is using a TGraph2D in [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTGraph2D.html#a52f2eb4c4cf50b7d086e3e7abe25d647). Do you know any other solution? Numerical recipes maybe? Since I am writing C++ code I would prefer C or C++ implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since non answer has been given yet, but I am still working on this problem, I will share my progresses here.

The class TLinearFitter has a fit method that allows you to select Robust fitting - Least Trimmed Squares regression (LTS):

https://root.cern.ch/root/html532/TLinearFitter.html

Another possible solution, more time consuming maybe, but *maybe* more efficient on the long run is to write my own function to be minimized, and the use:
https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt to minimize it. Although in this approach there is a bigger "step". I don't know how to use the library and I haven't (yet?) found a nice tutorial to understand it.

here: https://wis.kuleuven.be/stat/robust/software there is a Fortran implementation of the LMedS algorithm called PROGRESS. So another possible solution could be to port this software to C/C++ and make a library out of it.

Comment: In the end I use TLinearFitter::EvalRobust method. It works well, it's major drawback is of course performance. SVD is so much faster.